# Oracle database connectivity error in netbeans

Tags: oracle10g, oracle11g, database-connection, netbeans-7

I am using netbeans to do a java application using oracle database 11g express edition. I am getting the following error while building the project.

"Error occured: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"

it gets solved when i re-install the database, but becomes an error after the next restart. I can connect to the database using SQL command line. Can any one tell me why this error occurs (I have already added the ojdbc6.jar file to the project).

Comment: Did you have created a connection with oracle thin to you databse in oracle?

Comment: Yes, i created connection with oracle thin

Answer (score 0):

Your database (or the Oracle listener) is not running. You're probably missing a start up script that starts the database automatically after a reboot.

If I'm not mistaken, you can chose during the installation whether the database should be automatically started when the computer boots.

If you provide more information about your installation (in particular the OS), then I can tell you how to start the database.

Comment: database starts automatically when the system starts. When i go to services, i can see OracleServiceXE as running. also i can connect using SQL Command Line